# Is it possible to see the number of confirmations and source address using Monero wallet CLI?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-confirmation, cli

GUI version provides number of confirmations and address from which coins were sent.
But I don't know how to see it using CLI version of wallet.
I tried to use `show_transactions` and `show_transaction <txid>`, but it didn't help.
`show_transaction <txid>` shows number of confirmations only for received coins, but not for sent coins. Why? And how to see the source address?
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If show_transaction does not show the number of confirmations, nothing else does. It should be pretty easy to add. Same thing for source.

Comment: how to add? screenshot of gui version with number of confirmations: https://i.imgur.com/5MfqPK6.png. source address(transaction details): https://i.imgur.com/MhWD4VO.png

Comment: src/simplewallet/simplewallet.cpp, in show_transfer, you'd add a similar print for out transactions as already exists for in transactions. Similar for addresses, but you'd have to recreate the address from subaddress indices I think. But same place.